# How did the Eastern & Western halves of the Confederacy communicate with each other after the fall of Vicksburg?

Tags: american-civil-war, confederacy

After the Union captured Vicksburg, they split the Confederacy in two. The separation was such that it's said Confederate general Kirby Smith effectively ran a "Kirby Smithdom" in the Western portion of the CSA.

Nonetheless, I can see evidence that the Confederacy continued to communicate with each other:

> Earlier that summer, the Confederacy had ordered General E. Kirby Smith, commander of the Trans-Mississippi Department, to send a corps under Lieutenant-General Richard Taylor across the Mississippi River to assist in the defense of Atlanta and Mobile. Such a crossing was impossible because of Union gunboat patrols on the river and Taylor was assigned to other duties.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price%27s_Missouri_Expedition#Background). Presumably if the two parts were unable to communicate, the Confederacy would not be able to send orders to Kirby Smith in the first place.

Similarly, for this order to make sense, Richard Taylor must be in the Western part of the CSA, and indeed he was, since he was in command of the Red River Campaign. Yet in 1865, he was in the Eastern part:

> Taylor was given command of the Department of Alabama, Mississippi, and East Louisiana. After General John Bell Hood's disastrous campaign into Tennessee and near destruction of his army at the Battle of Franklin, Taylor was briefly given command of the Army of Tennessee, until most of its remnant was sent to contest Sherman's march further north through the Carolinas from Savannah. He surrendered his department at Citronelle, Alabama, the third and last major Confederate force remaining east of the Mississippi, to Union General Edward Canby on May 4, 1865, almost a month after Appomattox Courthouse and was paroled three days later.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Taylor_(Confederate_general)#Last_days_of_the_war). This indicates there must not only have been cross-river communication, it must have been possible for the CSA to move men across the river, even though they can't move large groups of men. How did that work with the Union in command of the river?

Comment: ‘Command’does not mean an iron curtain. A few people in a rowboat can make it across with orders. You just don’t have the ability to move significant men and materiel since that takes concentrating the men and boats in one place, making them an easy target for the patrols to notice and act.

Comment: This tale does not surprise me. Smugglers today use small boats at night to cross rivers. Actually, the police tried a navy radar, experimentally, at Iguaçu Dam Lake, between Brazil and Paraguay, and the radar spotted 30 small boats on a single night. How many men are needed to patrol a long river such as the Mississippi?  You must be very close to spot a small boat rowing at night.

Comment: @JonCuster do you know of any source that gives that as the method by which Richard Taylor crossed the river?